# Android: sql query to CONTENT_URI

Tags: android, sqlite, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-contentresolver

Hello every androids developers! Please would you help with one question.
I am trying

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Contacts.CONTENT_URI,CONTACT_PROJECTION, n" _id = _id ) GROUP BY ("+ Calls.NUMBER, null, "cnt DESC");
```

and it is work fine in Android 2.3.3, but at the Android 4.03 it is crashed because Android 4.03 do not support anymore GROUP BY queries. 
( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837544/android-ics-sqlite-error )

So i decide to form raw sql query to URI Contacts.CONTENT_URI with example code

```
ContentProviderClient client =  getContentResolver().acquireContentProviderClient(AUTHORITY);
SQLiteDatabase dbHandle= ((MyContentProvider)client.getLocalContentProvider()).getDbHandle();                    
Cursor cursor = dbHandle.rawQuery("SELECT _id, date, duration, number, type, name,   numbertype, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM calls WHERE ( 1=1 ) GROUP BY (number) ORDER BY cnt DESC", null);
```

or with

```
SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
qb.query(db, projectionIn, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, sortOrder)
```

that have groupBy parameter.

But i do not understood how to get dbHandle from CONTENT_URI or db name of CONTENT_URI in second case.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

Do not do SQL injection in Android.
For Google will fix its bug.

The GroupBy Should be called in the ContentProvider. Not the ContentResolver.

Comment: But where here i will get ContentProvider.query(...) if i using CotentReslover.query(...). I must using dbHandle.rawQuery(...) but i do not know how to get dbHandle